# HIVE Select record with the most recent create date if there are more than one record with the same account number

Tags: hive

I have the following table and I need to add a condition that indicates that if there is more than one record having the same acct_id, then choose the record with the most recent create date.

| acct_id | name | role | create_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | abc | Support | 2022-02-21 11:32:32.259000011 |
| 12345 | abc | Support | 2022-02-21 11:32:32.259000456 |
| 54321 | def | Product | 2022-02-21 11:32:32.259000678 |
| 54321 | def | Product | 2022-02-21 11:32:32.259000890 |
| 34561 | fhi | Accounts | 2022-02-21 11:32:32.259000320 |

Comment: `MySQL` <> `SQL Server`. Please update the tag

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: this qn has 3 different system. OP please specify which tool you are using - hive/sql server/mysql ?

Answer (score 0):

Below code snipper will get the acct_id record with latest create_date desc.

```
WITH source_data AS
(
   select acct_id,name,role,create_date,
   row_number() over(partition by acct_id order by create_date desc) rnk
from <source_table>
)
select * from source_data where rnk = 1
;
```